# How can i add an id and selector to nsdictionary?

Tags: ios

How can i add an id and selector to nsdictionary? These doesn't works:

```
id target = mainTarget;
    SEL selector=mainSelector;
    NSDictionary *tAndS=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:target,@"target",selector,@"selector", nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the
>   NSCopying protocol—see below)

A selector does not conform to NSCopying, but you *can* convert one to a string (which does conform to the protocol):

```
NSString* sel = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(hello:));
```

The `id` is no different. If your object conforms to `NSCopying` then you're good to go. If not, you'll have to wrap it in something that does, such as `NSData` or just implement `NSCopying` (the latter would be "cleanest").

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSMutableDictionary like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *tAndS = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[tAndS setObject:target forKey:selector];
```

Comment: A mutable dictionary has exactly the same constraints as a non-mutable one. Except mutability, obviously.